# "If" statement not working with optional value

Tags: swift, uitextfield

My problem is that I have some text fields that the user enters in numbers, the entered numbers then get saved to the corresponding variable.

However if the user doesn't enter a number and leaves it blank, the text field has a value of 'nil' and so would crash if unwrapped.

So I used an if statement to only unwrap if the contents of the test field are NOT nil, however this doesn't work. My program still unwraps it and crashes because the value is nil...

I don't understand how my if statement is not catching this.

On another note, how do I change my if statement to only allow Int values to be unwrapped and stored, strings or anything else would be ignored.

```
@IBAction func UpdateSettings() {
    if CriticalRaindays.text != nil {
        crit_raindays = CriticalRaindays.text.toInt()!
    }
    if EvapLess.text != nil {
        et_raindays_lessthan_11 = EvapLess.text.toInt()!
    }
    if EvapMore.text != nil {
        et_raindays_morethan_11 = EvapMore.text.toInt()!
    }
    if MaxWaterStorage.text != nil {
        max_h2Ostore = MaxWaterStorage.text.toInt()!
    }
    if CarryForward.text != nil {
        carry_forward = CarryForward.text.toInt()!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that while the text exists, it doesn't mean `toInt()` will return a value.

Say the text was `abc`, `CriticalRaindays.text != nil` would be true but `CriticalRaindays.text.toInt()!` can still be `nil`, because `abc` cannot be converted to an Int.

The exact cause of your crash is likely that `.text` is equal to `""`, the empty string. It's not `nil`, but definitely not an `Int` either.

The better solution is to use optional binding to check the integer conversion and see if that passes, instead of merely the string existing:

```
 if let rainDays = CriticalRaindays.text.toInt() {
     crit_raindays = rainDays
 }
```

If that doesn't compile, you possibly need to do Optional chaining:

`if let rainDays = CriticalRaindays.text?.toInt()`

Not on a Mac atm so can't test it for you but hope this makes sense!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it makes sense however it still cause it to crash (very strange). I had to you the optional changing method you mentioned. Even using a if let statement it still crashed "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I am very confused as to how this can happen because isn't the whole point of an if let, that if it is nil then just skip it...

Comment: Ok, I have figured out the problem. Using this does not work; "if let rain days = CriticalRaindays.text?.toInt()!". I presume its because it is force unwrapping the optional in the process of the if statement and so crashes the app, however removing the "!" at the end works just fine! So my final code that works; "if let raindays = CriticalRaindays.text.toInt()" I realise now that you had written this all along... I still had the "!" hence why it was not working, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Haha yes, you need to remove the `!` or else it will crash anyways. :]

Answer (score 0):

In your `ViewDidLoad`, set `CarryForward.text = ""` This way it will never be nil

Edit:

To check if a textfield is empty, you can use this:

```
if (CarryForward.text.isEmpty) {
    value = 10
}
else {
    value = CarryForward.text
}
```

Comment: Yes this would solve the problem of not crashing the app, however I cannot use this solution because these values need specific values, lets say 10. So what I'm trying to do is have a default set at 10, but if the user wants to change the settings then they can (leaving it blank would not change the setting), if I set it to "", then my default value of 10 would disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an `if let` to unwrap on if the the text field's text is non-nil?

```
if let textString = self.textField.text as String! {
    // do something with textString, we know it contains a value
}
```

Comment: I have tried this adding this code underneath;
    myVariable = textString
 but for some reason there is an error: "Use of unresolved identifier "textstring" (using your example). How can this be if the variable has just be declared in the if let statement?

Comment: Nevermind, this was just Xcode bugging out, had to close and reopen and error was gone, works now :) However I still have a problem, I am dealing with "Int" not "String". I tried to simply replace the word String with Int, but that did not work: "String is not convertible to Int"